# "Failed to load resource" error on client

Tags: asp.net, web, client-server, single-page-application

I run my web project but I get this error on client side:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:32573/favicon.ico
```

I am using:

- Visual Studio2013
- AngularJS
- jQuery
- Bootstrap

Any idea what cause to this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mime type, from IIS add **.ico** with mimeType **image/x-icon**

Or in web config if you do not want to set up mime type on your default website (this is used now: http://localhost:32573)

Go in web config and set up this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
   </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```